# C# Grid view not populating from a working proc

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

i have a c# data grid that is not populating when entering a code to a text box. there is a button click that triggers my proc in my sql.

When pass the code in the sql like below it brings back the correct results (below)

```
 Exec [dbo].[Get_Elec_Tariffs] '0380123'
```

I have tried to pass the parameter via the c# however even thought i do not have any error the grid is not visible. i have including the code which i beileve should work below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DataApp;
using AppLogic;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace QT_Test
{
    public partial class Elec_Tariffs : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var get_tariff = Calldatabase.Get_Elec_Tariff(Convert.ToString(TextBox1.Text));

            GridView1.DataSource = get_tariff;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And

```cs
public static List<Get_Elec_TariffsResult> Get_Elec_Tariff(string MTC_Code)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataAppDBDataContext())
    {
       return ctx.Get_Elec_Tariffs(MTC_Code).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Could you shou us part of code `from Get_Elec_Tariffs`? and are you using `EF`?

Comment: Stick a debug line above your `return ctx.Get_Elec_Tariffs(MTC_Code).ToList();`.  Something like `Console.WriteLine("Found " + ctx.Get_Elec_Tariffs(MTC_Code).ToList().Count() + " records");` to see how much data you're getting.